# How do I color a text inside a non-vuetify component (i.e. normal HTML elements)?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to color an `<h3>` element with my accent color that I specified in `@/plugins/vuetify.js`. I tried doing it like `<h3 class="text--accent">My colored text</h3>` but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **vuetify classes**

```
<h3 class="red--text">My colored text</h3>
```